# Scraping Google News with pygooglenews

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, pygooglenews

I am trying to do scraping from Google News with [`pygooglenews`](https://github.com/kotartemiy/pygooglenews).
I am trying to scrape more than 100 articles at a time (as google sets limit at 100) by changing the target dates using for loop. The below is what I have so far but I keep getting error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-4ada7169ebe7> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame(get_news('Banana'))
      2 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('My Result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
      3 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results', index=False)
      4 writer.save()

<ipython-input-79-c5266f97934d> in get_titles(search)
      9 
     10     for date in date_list[:-1]:
---> 11         search = gn.search(search, from_=date, to_=date_list[date_list.index(date)])
     12         newsitem = search['entries']
     13 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygooglenews\__init__.py in search(self, query, helper, when, from_, to_, proxies, scraping_bee)
    140         if from_ and not when:
    141             from_ = self.__from_to_helper(validate=from_)
--> 142             query += ' after:' + from_
    143 
    144         if to_ and not when:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'
```

```
import pandas as pd
from pygooglenews import GoogleNews
import datetime

gn = GoogleNews()

def get_news(search):
    stories = []
    start_date = datetime.date(2021,3,1)
    end_date = datetime.date(2021,3,5)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    date_list = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date).tolist()
    
    for date in date_list[:-1]:
        search = gn.search(search, from_=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), to_=(date+delta).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        newsitem = search['entries']

        for item in newsitem:
            story = {
                'title':item.title,
                'link':item.link,
                'published':item.published
            }
            stories.append(story)

    return stories

df = pd.DataFrame(get_news('Banana'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify where this error is coming from, i.e., could you share the full traceback? Also, which `pygooglenews` library are you using exactly?

Comment: Hi p3j4p5, thanks for your response. Apologies for lack of explanation. I've updated my post with error messages and also the link to the library that I am using.

Comment: Thanks @will418 - This helped, I've written an answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! Is there anything I can do to support your work?

Comment: You are very welcome. If you could _accept_ and _upvote_ the answer, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are correctly passing in a string into `get_news()` which is then passed on as the first argument (`search`) into `gn.search()`.

However, you're reassigning `search` to the result of `gn.search()` in the line:

```py
  search = gn.search(search, from_=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), to_=(date+delta).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
# ^^^^^^
# gets overwritten with the result of gn.search()
```

In the next iteration this reassigned `search` is passed into `gn.search()` which it doesn't like.

If you look at the code in [`pygooglenews`](https://github.com/kotartemiy/pygooglenews/blob/aca41c711a34d8c3e0bb97d0f7acc242c557c148/pygooglenews/__init__.py#L156), it looks like `gn.search()` is returning a `dict` which would explain the error.

To fix this, simply use a different variable, e.g.:

```py
result = gn.search(search, from_=date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), to_=(date+delta).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
newsitem = result['entries']
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that pygooglenews has a limit of 100 articles, so you must to make a loop in which it will scrape every day separately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).